# How remove controls from wrappanel?

Tags: c#, uwp, wrappanel

I use custom realization of wrap panel for UWP https://github.com/gregstoll/UniversalWrapPanel. I add some buttons to panel, but i dont understand how remove all items from it.

```
 <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <wrapControl:WrapPanel x:Name="wrapper" Margin="10" Grid.Column="2" Background="Bisque">

           </wrapControl:WrapPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

I try use this code

```
wrapper.Children.Remove(0);
```

Its work correct, but i dont know how foreach all items from wrapper and remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
wrapper.Children.Clear();
```